# When TextBox.Text is set to string.Empty explicitly it starts to add each next char to the beginning

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

When TextBox.Text is set to string.Empty explicitly it starts to add each next char to the beginning.

That is, after I set TextBox.Text = string.Empty,
I tap on the TextBox and start to click on the virtual keyboard keys,
for example in the following order: ABCD

But textbox will show DCBA instead.

What is that and how to force the TextBox to insert keys into a proper place?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting to ""? That works for me.

```
TextBox.Text = "";
```

Although, honestly, there should be no difference between the two. I have plenty of TextBoxes reset to "" and this problem hasn't occurred for me.

Comment: I've found the problem. Text was binded to the string prop in a ViewModel, and that prop's setter called value.ToUpper(). Somehow, this leads to this strange effect.

Comment: Haha. Funky! I'll watch out for that in the future. :)

Answer (score 0):

The effect described above was triggered by the fact that the property to which it was binded called ToUpper() on value:

```
private string word;
public string Word {
        get { return word; }
        set {
            word = value.ToUpper();
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Word);
        }
    }
```

Seems like a bug somewhere.